# How to access data from mongoose model with three schemas

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose-schema

Hello I am needing assistance with accessing certain data from my mongoose schema in my route to render it on the UI. I have 3 json files with objects like so,

```
{
  "name": "1_test_spec.rb",
  "folder": "working_1",
  "test": "Test 1 TC 134389 Add to Autopay with Visa"
}
```

I imported the json files to my local mongoDB with each file having its own collection. The name format is test_working1/2/3. I than created the following schema.

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

//SCHEMA SETUP
const test_working1Schema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: String,
  folder: String,
  test: String
});

const test_working2Schema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: String,
  folder: String,
  test: String
});

const test_working3Schema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: String,
  folder: String,
  test: String
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("Test_working1", test_working1Schema);
module.exports = mongoose.model("Test_working2", test_working2Schema);
module.exports = mongoose.model("Test_working3", test_working2Schema);
```

Than at the top of my .js file I require the schema `Test = require("../models/test")`,I have my routes set up like so,

```
router.get("/", (req, res) => {
  Test.find({}, (err, allTests) => {
    if(err){
        console.log(err);
    }  else {
      res.render("automation/index", { test: allTests, username: req.user });
    }
  });
});



router.get("/:id/test", (req, res) =>{
  Test.findById(req.params.id, (err, foundTest) => {
    let folder = foundTest.folder;
    let name = foundTest.name;
    let test = foundTest.test;

      if(err){
          console.log(err);
      } else {
        ChildProcess.exec(`cd ${path} & cd ../../ & cd ./automation/WSS_Automation & rspec ./spec/tests/` + folder + "/" + name, (error, stdout, stderr) => {
        console.log('stdout: ' + stdout);
        console.log('stderr: ' + stderr);
        console.log('error: ' + error);
        });
        req.flash("added", test + " " + "is running!" );
        res.redirect("/QAApplicationHub/Automation/");
        // res.send("WSS " + test + ' ' + "is running!");
      }
  });
});
```

The above route handles comparing the name of the folder that each test is in and which test the user selects to run by comparing the ID. I than call to the data from the UI using EJS,

```
<select class="form-control col-md-4 slct001">
        <option value="">Choose one...</option>
        <% test.forEach(function(test){ %>
        <option value="/QAApplicationHub/Automation/<%= test._id %>/test"><%= test.test %></option>
        <% }); %>
      </select>
```

The issue here is that it is only displaying the test files from test_working3. The goal is to have three separate select drop downs. Each select element will contain the test from each folder. The user will select the test they want to run and select a button to run the automation test script.

Im sure there is a more efficient way of doing this. Im only familiar with working with one schema and route pair at a time so this is a little bit more than I have exposure too. Any assistance is appreciated. Thanks.

Update:

I updated my schema to this,

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

//SCHEMA SETUP
const test_working1Schema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: String,
  folder: String,
  test: String
});

const test_working2Schema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: String,
  folder: String,
  test: String
});

const test_working3Schema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: String,
  folder: String,
  test: String
});


const Test1 = mongoose.model("Test_working1", test_working1Schema);
const Test2 = mongoose.model("Test_working2", test_working2Schema);
const Test3 = mongoose.model("Test_working3", test_working3Schema);

module.exports = { Test1, Test2, Test3 }
```

I than included it on my .js file like this,

```
const Test1          = require("../models/test").Test1,
      Test2          = require("../models/test").Test2,
      Test3          = require("../models/test").Test3;
```

And my route looks like this,

```
router.get("/", (req, res) => {
  Test1.find({}, (err, allTests) => {
    if(err){
        console.log(err);
    }
      else {
      res.render("automation/index", { test1: allTests, username: req.user 
     });
    }
  });
});
```

Is there a way to pass in each model from the one route similar to how I use `Test1.find({}`.....or that should be handled inside of the schema instead?

Alright so to make things easier I hope I changed the structure of the json file and schema to the correct format. So now my Json file is like this

```
{"working1": [{

  "name": "1_test_spec.rb",
  "folder": "working_1",
  "test": "Test 1 TC 134389 Add to Autopay with Visa"
},
  {
  "name": "2_test_spec.rb",
  "folder": "working_1",
  "test": "Test 2 TC 134389 Add to Autopay with Master Card"
  }
  ]}

  {"working2": [{

    "name": "11_test_spec.rb",
    "folder": "working_2",
    "test": "Test 11 TC 149627 Create a Confirmed Reservation"
  },
    {
      "name": "12_test_spec.rb",
      "folder": "working_2",
      "test": "Test 12 TC 149630 Create Online Reservation"
    }
    ]}

    {"working3": [{
        "name": "21_test_spec.rb",
        "folder": "working_3",
        "test": "Test 21 TC 161117 Move Out with visa Card Refund"
      },
      {
        "name": "22_test_spec.rb",
        "folder": "working_3",
        "test": "Test 22 TC 161117 Move Out with Cash Refund"
      }
      ]}
```

And I than updated the schema to this,

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

//SCHEMA SETUP
const testSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  working1: [{ name: String, folder: String, test: String}],
  working2: [{ name: String, folder: String, test: String}],
  working3: [{ name: String, folder: String, test: String}]

});

module.exports = mongoose.model("Test", testSchema);
```

That should make it easier to get the data I want into each select element drop down?

Answer (score 0):

It happens because in your file with the schema, only the last line is effective. i.e,

```
module.exports = mongoose.model("Test_working3", test_working2Schema);
```

overwrites the earlier exports.

One file can only export one model in the way you are doing, and is the standard way of doing this. 
If you really want to export all three models from the same file, you can do something like:

```
module.exports = {
    test1 : mongoose.model("Test_working1", test_working1Schema),
    test2 : mongoose.model("Test_working2", test_working2Schema);
    test3 : mongoose.model("Test_working3", test_working2Schema);
}
```

And require all 3 schemas, using

```
var Test1 = require("../models/test").test1
var Test2 = require("../models/test").test2
var Test3 = require("../models/test").test3
```

and then, render the data from each 3 of these separately. Something like this:

```
var async = require('async')
router.get("/", (req, res) => {
    async.parallel({
        test1: function (callback1) {
            Test1.findOne({}, callback1)
        },
        test2: function (callback2) {
            Test2.findOne({}, callback2)
        },
        test3: function (callback3) {
            Test3.findOne({}, callback3)
        },

    }, function (err, results) {
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            var tests = test1.concat(test2).concat(test3);
            res.render("automation/index", { test1: tests, username: req.user });
        }
    })
});
```

Comment: Hey thank you for your response, that solved my issue with the schema, however is there a way to include all three Test1, Test2, and Test3 in the one route that I have for Test.find({}, allTests) ect.....

Comment: You can do it by fetching the data from all three collections independently, and be concatenating their values to your output. Since all three are different collections, don't think there is a way to query all three of them in one go. Updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Doing this:

```
module.exports = mongoose.model("Test_working1", test_working1Schema);
module.exports = mongoose.model("Test_working2", test_working2Schema);
module.exports = mongoose.model("Test_working3", test_working2Schema);
```

I think you are exporting only the last one, because you are overwriting exports with different values, and only last one "survives". Probably that makes you only get results from the 3rd schema.

Whay I suggest you to do is to export the methods you need, for example a find method and a findById method, and implement each method into the db file searching in the 3 models for results and returning all of them. Something like this:

```
const model1 = mongoose.model("Test_working1", test_working1Schema);
const model2 = mongoose.model("Test_working2", test_working2Schema);
const model3 = mongoose.model("Test_working3", test_working2Schema);

exports.find = async query => {
    let result1 = await model1.find(query).toArray(); 
    let result2 = await model2.find(query).toArray(); 
    let result3 = await model3.find(query).toArray(); 
    return [...result1, ...result2, ...result3];
}

exports.findById = async id => {
    // something similar
}
```